# Amcharts graph - Rotate chart to horizontal at lesser screen-width

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to make amchart graph with function that it rotates and becomes horizontal when screenwidth is less than 766px. If screenwidth is less than 766 px, value axes should be on top and category axes should be on the left

I added this script link -

```
<script src="amcharts/plugins/responsive/responsive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and also added this code to the amcharts API code  -

```
"responsive": {
    "enabled": true,
    "addDefaultRules": false,
    "rules": [{
        "maxWidth": 766,
        "overrides": {
            "rotate": true,
            "categoryAxis": {
                "position": "left"
            },
            "valueAxes": {
                "position": "top"
            }
        }
    }]
},
```

But still it does not work. The chart does not revert to horizontal on decreasing screen-width less than 766px. Please tell what I am doing wrong. I do not want to use Jquery and I am new to javascript. Would appreciate if you can show in a jsfiddle or a snippet.

This is my jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/fvurj0xg/ and below is my snippet -

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "addClassNames": true,
 "responsive": {
        "enabled": true,
     "addDefaultRules": false,
     "rules": [{
            "maxWidth": 766,
            "overrides": {
                "rotate": true,
                "categoryAxis": {
                    "position": "left"
                },
                "valueAxes": {
                    "position": "top"
                }
            }
        }]
      },
      "titles": [{
        "text": "Open this demo in a separate window for links to work"
      }],
      "dataProvider": [{
        "country": "USA",
        "visits": 2025,
        "url": "https://codepen.io"
      }, {
        "country": "China",
        "visits": 1882,
        "url": "https://codepen.io"
      }, {
        "country": "Japan",
        "visits": 1809,
        "url": "https://codepen.io"
      }, {
        "country": "Germany",
        "visits": 1322,
        "url": "https://codepen.io"
      }, {
        "country": "UK",
        "visits": 1122,
        "url": "https://codepen.io"
      }, {
        "country": "France",
        "visits": 1114,
        "url": "https://codepen.io"
      }, {
        "country": "India",
        "visits": 984,
        "url": "https://codepen.io"
      }, {
        "country": "Spain",
        "visits": 711,
        "url": "https://codepen.io"
      }, {
        "country": "Netherlands",
        "visits": 665,
        "url": "https://codepen.io"
      }, {
        "country": "Russia",
        "visits": 580,
        "url": "https://codepen.io"
      }, {
        "country": "South Korea",
        "visits": 443,
        "url": "https://codepen.io"
      }, {
        "country": "Canada",
        "visits": 441,
        "url": "https://codepen.io"
      }, {
        "country": "Brazil",
        "visits": 395,
        "url": "https://codepen.io"
      }],
      "valueAxes": [{
          "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
          "gridAlpha": 0.2,
          "dashLength": 0
      }],
      "gridAboveGraphs": true,
      "startDuration": 1,
      "graphs": [{
          "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
          "fillAlphas": 0.8,
          "lineAlpha": 0.2,
          "type": "column",
          "valueField": "visits"
      }],
      "chartCursor": {
          "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
          "cursorAlpha": 0,
          "zoomable": false
      },
      "categoryField": "country",
      "categoryAxis": {
          "gridPosition": "start",
          "gridAlpha": 0,
          "tickPosition": "start",
          "tickLength": 20,
      "listeners": [{
          "event": "clickItem",
          "method": function(event) {
              var url = event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url; 
              window.open(url, '_blank'); 
          }
      }]
    }

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.amcharts-axis-label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="amcharts/plugins/responsive/responsive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the url to `responsive.min.js` is not correct. Try to add a correct one then it should work. Here the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fvurj0xg/1/

Comment: Thanks. Working now. Can you give the source where you got the correct responsive amchart link. Because in their official docs, they have mentioned this url only - https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/making-charts-responsive/

Comment: take a look at Amcharts repository from here https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3. We can find where responsive plugin located

Comment: Thanks for the repository link @vnt But even this documentation shows the responsive url which I have added - https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3/tree/master/amcharts/plugins/responsive

Comment: On googling the url provided by you, I found this resource link of amcharts. Putting it for the benefit of others - http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/resources.php